# Liquid gives the wrong link

Tags: url, shopify, liquid

I'm creating a pagination in my website with Liquid template engine. But the link does not work as it should.

I want this link: https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets/filter?page=2&requested_by=0&wf_filter=all

But I get this link: https://support.beefinity.com/support/tickets/filter/page/2?requested_by=0&url_locale=&wf_filter=all

This is the code that I use for the pagination:

```
{% paginate tickets by 10 %} {% for ticket in tickets %} {% if ticket.group.name == "Beefinity Support"%}

<div class="c-row c-ticket-row" id="ticket-view">
    <span class="status-source sources-detailed-{{ticket.source_name | downcase}}" title=" {{ticket.source_name | downcase}} "></span> <span class="label-status-pending label label-small">{{ticket.status}}</span>

    <div class="ticket-brief">
        <div class="ellipsis">
            <a class="c-link" href="{{ticket.portal_url}}" title="{{ticket.subject}}">{{ticket.subject}}</a>
        </div>


        <div class="help-text">
            Made by: <span class="emphasize">{{ticket.requester.name}} &nbsp; Made on:{{ ticket.created_on | date: "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M" }}</span><br>
            Agent: <span class="emphasize">{{ticket.agent.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %} {% endfor %} {% if paginate.pages != 0 %}

    <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
      <ul>
        {% if paginate.previous %}
          <li class="previous">
            <a rel="prev start" href="{{ paginate.previous.url }}">
              {{ paginate.previous.title }} Previous
            </a>
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled">
            <span>&laquo; Previous </span>
          </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for part in paginate.parts %}
          {% if part.is_link %}
            <li>
              <a rel="prev start" href="{{ part.url }}">
                {{ part.title }}
              </a>
            </li>
          {% else %}
            {% if part.title == paginate.current_page %}
              <li class="active">
                {{ part.title }}
              </li>
            {% else %}
              <li>
                <a rel"start"> {{ part.title }}</a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if paginate.next %}
          <li class="next_page">
            <a rel="next" href="{{ paginate.next.url }}">
              Next {{ paginate.next.title }}
            </a>
          </li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="next_page disabled">
            <span> Next &raquo; </span>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

in the documentation that I viewed it just goes well:
[image: The documentation]

Comment: How is this related to Shopify?

Comment: @HymnZ Liquid is an open-source template language created by Shopify https://shopify.github.io/liquid/